# C# - Change font of text in RichTextBox dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, richtextbox

I am having some text in a "richTextBox" and a "comboBox" having names of some fonts. I want to change the font of text in "richTextBox" if a new font is selected from the "comboBox". I am using following code.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14);
}
```

The problem is that if I select the font, the text does not change its font automatically, it only changes if I type some new text.  I also tried `richTextBox1.SelectionFont` instead of `richTextBox1.Font`. I also added `InputTextBox.Refresh();` after the above code to refresh the text box but in vein.

How I can change font of the text by just selecting from comboBox?

**Update:** I just figured out that above code is fine, the problem is that I was using wrong event call, used `comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged()` in place of `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()` and it works fine now.

**Tip:** If you want to change font of entire TextBox use `richTextBox1.Font`, if you want to change font of selected text only use `richTextBox1.SelectionFont`.

Answer (score 10):

You could select all the text before changing `SelectedFont` option:

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectAll();
this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = newFont;
```

Comment: The problem was not of selecting text, actually I was using wrong event. I have updated my question, see above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate throughout your text for that. This is a method it might help you:

```
private void ChangeFontStyleForSelectedText(string familyName, float? emSize, FontStyle? fontStyle, bool? enableFontStyle)
    {
        _maskChanges = true;
        try
        {
            int txtStartPosition = txtFunctionality.SelectionStart;
            int selectionLength = txtFunctionality.SelectionLength;
            if (selectionLength > 0)
                using (RichTextBox txtTemp = new RichTextBox())
                {
                    txtTemp.Rtf = txtFunctionality.SelectedRtf;
                    for (int i = 0; i < selectionLength; ++i)
                    {
                        txtTemp.Select(i, 1);
                        txtTemp.SelectionFont = RenderFont(txtTemp.SelectionFont, familyName, emSize, fontStyle, enableFontStyle);
                    }

                    txtTemp.Select(0, selectionLength);
                    txtFunctionality.SelectedRtf = txtTemp.SelectedRtf;
                    txtFunctionality.Select(txtStartPosition, selectionLength);
                }
        }
        finally
        {
            _maskChanges = false;
        }
    }
```

If you want to see how I did this you can read this article: http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2014/01/how-to-make-custom-richtextbox-control.html 
Good luck ;)